# What is a Sharp Word?

Tags: word, wordplay, english

(Based off and inspired by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)'s [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) puzzles)

## What Is A Sharp Word?

Word that conform to a specific rule are called **sharp** words.
Here are some examples:

| Sharp Words™ | Non-Sharp Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WALLOW | BATHE |
| WALK | STROLL |
| SHORES | BEACH |
| OTTER | SEAL |
| DUSTY | DIRTY |
| DUMP | TOSS |
| GENOME | GENETICS |
| LAUGH | GIGGLE |
| GRUNT | HARUMPH |
| PITA | IXTLE |

In CSV format:

```
Sharp Words™,Non-Sharp Words™
WALLOW,BATHE
WALK,STROLL
SHORES,BEACH
OTTER,SEAL
DUSTY,DIRTY
DUMP,TOSS
GENOME,GENETICS
LAUGH,GIGGLE
GRUNT,HARUMPH
PITA,IXTLE
```

What determines whether a word is or isn't a Sharp Word™? Why is it called a Sharp Word™?

HINT 1:

> The last letter may be more important than you think.

HINT 2:

> The word simply *can't* remain as is...

Comment: Time for a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a Sharp word is

> one whose letters, excluding the last, form another word through  rearrangement.

For example:

> 'Genome' forms 'gnome' and 'wallow' forms 'allow'. However 'bathe' doesn't qualify, because 'bath' is not a rearrangement, i.e., the letters remain "as is".

It is called "Sharp" because

> 'Sharp' is another such word.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) What about TOSS though? [SOT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sot) is a word (and 'TOS' is not) yet it is classed as Non-Sharp here...

Comment: @Stiv I noticed that, but hoped it was just an oversight, or that the author was going for common words.

Comment: What is your word for "laugh", is it "Gaul"? Because that opens up another issue.

Comment: Correct, that's the word I came up with.

Comment: Yeah, because you're allowing the use of proper nouns this disqualifies some more of the Non-Sharp words such as "harumph" (because of [Amphur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphoe)) and "beach" (because of [Beca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beca_(artist_group)))

Comment: @Stiv wow, there are a lot more words than I expected... I tried to go for simple words.

Comment: @hexomino I tried to go for the more common words. And laugh actually should have been removed.

Comment: @TheJokester You might find it useful when creating a question like this to use an [anagram solver](https://www.thewordfinder.com/anagram-solver/) to double-check your intended solution. In fact, whatever the puzzle type it's always good practice to double- and triple-check it before posting. The more you create, the more you'll get used to doing it :)

Comment: @Stiv I'll definitely do that in the future, thank you for the feedback!